# python3 interpret ascii string as unicode string

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I have a text file, that when opened, looks like this:

```
\xF0\x9F\x98\x81
\xF0\x9F\x98\x82
\xF0\x9F\x98\x83
\xF0\x9F\x98\x84
\xF0\x9F\x98\x85
```

The hexdump looks like this:

```
0000000 5c 78 46 30 5c 78 39 46 5c 78 39 38 5c 78 38 31
0000010 0a 5c 78 46 30 5c 78 39 46 5c 78 39 38 5c 78 38
0000020 32 0a 5c 78 46 30 5c 78 39 46 5c 78 39 38 5c 78
0000030 38 33 0a 5c 78 46 30 5c 78 39 46 5c 78 39 38 5c
0000040 78 38 34 0a 5c 78 46 30 5c 78 39 46 5c 78 39 38
```

I am trying to print the strings in Python as though the are unicode strings. The following things all fail:

```
with open ("file") as f:
    for row in f:
        x = row.split()
        for i in x:
            print(i)
            print(bytes(i, encoding='utf-8'))
            print(bytes(i, encoding='utf-8').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

Prints

```
\xF0\x9F\x98\x81
b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x81'
ð 
\xF0\x9F\x98\x82
b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x82'
ð
\xF0\x9F\x98\x83
b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x83'
ð
\xF0\x9F\x98\x84
b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x84'
ð
\xF0\x9F\x98\x85
b'\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x85'
ð
```

What I am TRYING to achieve is as if I typed the following directly:

```
print(b'\xF0\x9F\x98\x81'.decode('utf-8'))
print(b'\xF0\x9F\x98\x82'.decode('utf-8'))
print(b'\xF0\x9F\x98\x83'.decode('utf-8'))
print(b'\xF0\x9F\x98\x84'.decode('utf-8'))
print(b'\xF0\x9F\x98\x85'.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: also, opening the file as 'rb' and printing (`i.decode('utf-8')`) also fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unicode-escape` gives a Unicode string with the codepoints as specified. `latin1` converts it directly back to a byte string because there is a 1:1 mapping between `latin1` and the first 256 codepoints.  Finally decode back to Unicode using UTF-8.

```
data = rb'''\xF0\x9F\x98\x81
\xF0\x9F\x98\x82
\xF0\x9F\x98\x83
\xF0\x9F\x98\x84
\xF0\x9F\x98\x85'''

data = data.decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf8')
print(ascii(data))
print(data)
```

Output:

```
'\U0001f601\n\U0001f602\n\U0001f603\n\U0001f604\n\U0001f605'
```

Note: My font didn't support the characters.

Comment: There are dead spots in the [`'latin-1'` code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), does encode/decode treat those properly?

Comment: This does seem to work. Before accepting, though, does @markransom  raise a point I need to watch out for?

Comment: @MarkRansom, yes, per your link "ISO-8859-1 was incorporated as the first 256 code points of ISO/IEC 10646 and Unicode." (`latin1` is an alias for `iso-8859-1`) and it will correctly decode bytes 00h-FFh to Unicode codepoints U+0000 - U+00FF.

Comment: Another quote from @MarkRansom's link: "In 1992, the IANA registered the character map ISO_8859-1:1987, more commonly known by its preferred MIME name of ISO-8859-1 (note the extra hyphen over ISO 8859-1), a superset of ISO 8859-1, for use on the Internet. This map assigns the C0 and C1 control characters to the unassigned code values thus provides for 256 characters via every possible 8-bit value."

Comment: @Tommy apparently those byte values are valid, even though they don't map to printable characters. My characterizing them as "dead spots" was misleading. I now have some faith that the encode/decode will work for all 256 byte values, now and in the future.

Comment: This has been working as intended... guess a side question is why three steps are needed (why is this so complicated!)

Comment: @Tommy, it's complicated because the file contains hex escapes for UTF-8 bytes.  If the file had escape codes for Unicode codepoints instead, it could be a one-step operation.